# What is the use of formfeed and backspace escape strings in Java?

Tags: java, escaping

Is there any practical usage for `\r` and `\b` in Java? Could someone give an example where it's used?

Comment: Well, when you need to output/save those characters, it's pretty handy don't you think?

Comment: The question is not clear. The title references formfeed and backspace but the question references carriage return and backspace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually use `\r` together with `System.out.print` when printing some progress percentage.

Try running this in your terminal:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.print("Progress: " + i + " %\r");
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use \n instead of \r , it gives me the same results , what's the difference between two ? I guess \r is obsolete now.

Comment: See [this q/a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r).

Answer (score 16):

Formfeed escape is `\f`, not `\r`. The former is useful for clearing the screen in a console, whilst the second is useful for progress displays (as stated by aioobe).

`\b` can be used in progress displays also, for example, on a ICMP Ping, you could display a dot when a ping is sent and a `\b` when it is received to indicate the amount of packet loss.

Answer (score 8):

Form feed is `\f` and `\r` is carriage return.
`\f` is used for printing characters after it from new line starting just below previous character.

```
System.out.println("This is before\fNow new line");
System.out.println("TEXTBEFORE\rOverlap");
System.out.println("12\b3");
```

Output:

```
This is before
          Now new line
OverlapORE
13
```

Comment: I like this answer but you did not explain the bell character.

Comment: what the bell character has got to do here?

Comment: Never mind, \b is backspace. I was confusing \b with \a

Answer (score 3):

Form feed is a page-breaking ASCII control character. It forces the printer to eject the current page and to continue printing at the top of another. Often, it will also cause a carriage return. For further details click [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed)