# How to ensure only one file is returned by checking for newline

Tags: bash, unix, newline

What is the *simplest* way to check if a string contains newline?

For example, after

```
FILE=$(find . -name "pattern_*.sh")
```

I'd like to check for newline to ensure only one file matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To refer to your example: Note that filenames could contain newlines, too.

A safe way to count files would be

```
find -name "pattern_*.sh" -printf '\n' | wc -c
```

This avoids printing the filename and prints only a newline instead.

Comment: Or even `-printf 'x'` to save a character. No need to print newlines.

Comment: No need - true, but where do you save a character? Choose whatever you feel comfortable with...

Answer (score 17):

You can use pattern matching:

```
[[ $FILE == *$'\n'* ]] && echo More than one line
```

Comment: This is better without the dollar sign, in my situation.

Comment: I came here to answer "check if string contains newline bash", and in my case, I needed `'\r'`, instead of `'\n'`.

Comment: `\r` is not a newline, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1761051/1030675.

Answer (score 12):

If `$str` contains new line you can check it by,

```
if [ $(echo "$str" | wc -l) -gt 1 ];
then
     // perform operation if it has new lines
else
     // no new lines.
fi
```