# Replace comma with newline in sed on MacOS?

Tags: macos, unix, sed

I have a file of strings that are comma separated.  I'm trying to replace the commas with a new line.  I've tried:

```
sed 's/,/\n/g' file
```

but it is not working.  What am I missing?

Comment: try `tr , '\n'`. I guess, sed treats `\n` as plain text.

Comment: That worked!   cat file | tr , '\n'

Comment: `tr , '\n' < file` - no pipe.

Comment: What is the `g` in the end of the script for? I get the same behavior without it.

Comment: What shell are you using? This works for me, using the bash shell.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye The `g` will replace all instances of a character, whereas having no `g` will only only replace the first instance of that character per line.

Comment: Excuse me, @PrinceJohnWesley : is there any advantage on no piping? Maybe faster processing, or better RAM management?

Comment: See also the reversed question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114943/can-sed-replace-new-line-characters

Answer (score 417, accepted):

Use `tr` instead:

```
tr , '\n' < file
```

Comment: It is not wokring in bash shell
$ tr , '\n' aitr 
usage: tr [-Ccsu] string1 string2
       tr [-Ccu] -d string1
       tr [-Ccu] -s string1
       tr [-Ccu] -ds string1 string2

Comment: Replacing a comma with a semicolon also works: `tr ',' ';' < input.csv > output.csv`

Answer (score 348):

Use an [ANSI-C quoted string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) `$'string'`

You need a backslash-escaped literal newline to get to sed. 
In bash at least, `$''` strings will replace `\n` with a real newline, but then you have to double the backslash that sed will see to escape the newline, e.g.

```
echo "a,b" | sed -e $'s/,/\\\n/g'
```

Note [this will not work on all shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371827/do-shells-other-than-bash-and-zsh-support-ansi-c-quoting-e-g-string), but will work on the most common ones.

Comment: strange, it also works with one backslash less i.e. `echo "a,b" | sed -e $'s/,/\\n/g`.

Comment: Upvoted. For more info see the "QUOTING" section of `man bash`.

Comment: Got it working with OSX 10.11 : `sed -E $'s/<\\/br>/\\\n/g' file`, no need to install gnu-sed

Comment: Verified working on OS X 10.7 with the given example. The `-e` part seems not necessary.

Comment: OSX 10.10.5 requires 3 backslashes: `sed $'s/:/\\\n'/g <<<$PATH`

Comment: This is awesome! Using this with `fzf` for debugging my $PATH in case something is missing: `echo $PATH | sed -e $'s/:/\\\n/g' | fzf` ^.^

Comment: @Brice I think that `gsed -e 's/,/\n/g'` works on gnu-sed version 4.4-1.

Comment: I don't seem to need the '-e':  `echo foo,bar | sed $'s/,/\\n/g'`. ubuntu. sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

Comment: Thanks, is there any documentation reference on that please?

Comment: @YongweiWu, the `-e` is implicit if you only provide one command. If more than one command is wanted: `sed -e 's/foo/bar' -e 's/boo/far'`.

Answer (score 134):

```
sed 's/,/\
/g'
```

works on Mac OS X.

Comment: Thanks for this - Wondered why my old linux trick didn't work in OSX. But this does!

Comment: This is the only solution that works in a sed script.

Comment: Note that the backslash *escapes* the literal newline (so that it's not a command terminator): it is *not* a line continuation character (as in bash, etc.). To see the difference, try to write the above command without the quotes: the backslash will instead be interpreted by the shell as a line continuation character and it and the newline will be discarded. Conversely, include the contents of the quoted expression (without quotes) in a separate comma-to-newline.sed file (which eliminates shell syntax), and it works!

Comment: this is good since it can replace anything, not a character. tr seems work with only characters. if you put a string as first parameter, it will replace all the occurrence of the characters, not the string.

Comment: I'm on Yosemite, and I couldn't get this to work until I switched the escaped literal newline with *two* backslashes, not one.

Comment: @Droogans Are you using bash, sh, or a different shell?  Are you sure you're using single quotes instead of double quotes?

Comment: I can confirm it doesn't work on Yosemite.  I'm using single quotes, and it doesn't work for me on OSX 10.10.5.  No matter how many backslashes I use, I get the error: invalid command code  \

Comment: This gave me a clue. I did this in the end: `sed $'s/,/\\\n/'` to keep everything on one line

Answer (score 26):

If your sed usage tends to be entirely substitution expressions (as mine tends to be), you can also  use `perl -pe` instead

```
$ echo 'foo,bar,baz' | perl -pe 's/,/,\n/g'
foo,
bar,
baz
```

Answer (score 18):

MacOS is different, there is two way to solve this problem with sed in mac

- first ,use `\'$'\n''` replace  `\n`, it can work in MacOS:

  ```
  sed 's/,/\'$'\n''/g' file
  ```
- the second, just use an empty line:

  ```
  sed 's/,/\
  /g' file
  ```
- Ps. Pay attention the range separated by  `'`
- the third, use gnu-sed replace the mac-sed

Answer (score 17):

Apparently `\r` is the key!

```
$ sed 's/, /\r/g' file3.txt > file4.txt
```

Transformed this:

```
ABFS, AIRM, AMED, BOSC, CALI, ECPG, FRGI, GERN, GTIV, HSON, IQNT, JRCC, LTRE,
MACK, MIDD, NKTR, NPSP, PME, PTIX, REFR, RSOL, UBNT, UPI, YONG, ZEUS
```

To this:

```
ABFS
AIRM
AMED
BOSC
CALI
ECPG
FRGI
GERN
GTIV
HSON
IQNT
JRCC
LTRE
MACK
MIDD
NKTR
NPSP
PME
PTIX
REFR
RSOL
UBNT
UPI
YONG
ZEUS
```

Comment: I know the question says OS X, but this doesn't work with GNU sed-4.2.2-6.fc20.x86_64.

Comment: Keep in mind that `\r` is not the same as `\n`, and this might break further data manipulation and usage.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work for me. I just got an 'r' where there should be a newline.

Comment: You should make it more clear in the answer that this gives `\r`!

Comment: It worked for me but I wonder why! \n is the standard on unix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r

Comment: This didn't work for me either. I'm on macos 10.13 using /usr/bin/sed.

Answer (score 16):

This works on MacOS Mountain Lion (10.8), Solaris 10 (SunOS 5.10) and RHE Linux (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3, Tikanga)...

```
$ sed 's/{pattern}/\^J/g' foo.txt > foo2.txt
```

... where the `^J` is done by doing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>. Do mind the `\` before the `^J`.

PS, I know the sed in RHEL is GNU, the MacOS sed is FreeBSD based, and although I'm not sure about the Solaris sed, I believe this will work pretty much with any sed. YMMV tho'...

Answer (score 7):

To make it complete, this also works:

```
echo "a,b" | sed "s/,/\\$(echo -e '\n\r')/"
```

Comment: This would also be fitting for the Obfuscated C contest, except it's Bash ;)

Comment: @AaronR. I agree :-). Surely I prefer the `tr` solution, which is already the accepted answer.

Comment: This worked on OS X. Why is it `\n\r` instead of `\r\n`? I tried `\r\n` which is the necessary order on Windows. However, after I do this it's leaving a lot of `^M` carriage return characters in `vim`, so I think it's supposed to be only `\n` but `\n` alone doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Though I am late to this post, just updating my findings. This answer is only for **Mac OS X.**

```
$ sed 's/new/
> /g' m1.json > m2.json
sed: 1: "s/new/
/g": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern
```

In the above command I tried with Shift+Enter to add new line which didn't work. So this time I tried with "escaping" the "unescaped newline" as told by the error.

```
$ sed 's/new/\
> /g' m1.json > m2.json
```

**Worked! (in Mac OS X 10.9.3)**

Comment: This is no different than Max Nanasy's answer two years before yours.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo $PATH | sed -e $'s/:/\\\n/g' 
/usr/local/sbin
/Library/Oracle/instantclient_11_2/sdk
/usr/local/bin
```

...

Works for me on Mojave

Answer (score 2):

Just to clearify: man-page of sed on OSX (10.8; Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0) says:

[...]

#### Sed Regular Expressions

```
 The regular expressions used in sed, by default, are basic regular expressions (BREs, see re_format(7) for more information), but extended
 (modern) regular expressions can be used instead if the -E flag is given.  In addition, sed has the following two additions to regular
 expressions:

 1.   In a context address, any character other than a backslash (``\'') or newline character may be used to delimit the regular expression.
      Also, putting a backslash character before the delimiting character causes the character to be treated literally.  For example, in the
      context address \xabc\xdefx, the RE delimiter is an ``x'' and the second ``x'' stands for itself, so that the regular expression is
      ``abcxdef''.

 2.   The escape sequence \n matches a newline character embedded in the pattern space.  You cannot, however, use a literal newline charac-
      ter in an address or in the substitute command.
```

[...]

so I guess one have to use tr - as mentioned above - or the nifty

```
sed "s/,/^M
/g"
```

note: you have to type <*ctrl>*-v,<*return>* to get '^M' in vi editor

Answer (score 2):

The `sed` on macOS Mojave was released in 2005, so one solution is to install the `gnu-sed`,

```sh
brew install gnu-sed
```

then use `gsed` will do as you wish,

```sh
gsed 's/,/\n/g' file
```

If you prefer `sed`, just `sudo sh -c 'echo /usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin > /etc/paths.d/brew'`, which is suggested by `brew info gnu-sed`. Restart your term, then your `sed` in command line is `gsed`.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the following line works in windows and replaces semicolons in my path variables with a newline. I'm using the tools installed under my git bin directory.

```
echo %path% | sed -e $'s/;/\\n/g' | less
```

Answer (score -1):

I have found another command that is working also.

```
find your_filename.txt -type f -exec sed -i 's/,/\n/g' {} \;
```