# How do I replace : characters with newline?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I looked at a very similar question but was unable to resolve the issue [Replace comma with newline in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748453/replace-comma-with-newline-in-sed)

I am trying to convert `:` characters in a string. This is what I tried:

```
echo -e 'this:is:a:test' | sed "s/\:/'\n'/g"
```

but this replaces : with n. I tried tr too but had the same result. I believe the -e is not seen after being piped so new line is not recognized.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what system are you on? Your command pipeline works for me on RHEL

Comment: GNU `sed` appears to process `\n` as a newline (also in the much simpler `sed 's/:/\n/g'`; BSD `sed` does not.

Comment: yea that still has the same output for me : changes to n. This works tho which is weird echo -e ${PATH//:/'\n'}
which I don't really get the logic why.

Comment: You don't need the -e in the echo, that's for expanding meta-characters in the output of the echo statement, not the output of sed. You should be able to include a newline in sed without any escaping or quoting: **echo 'this:is:a:test' | sed "s/:/\n/g"** should work. If it doesn't, do a **sed --version** and  **echo $SHELL** to let us know what your environment is like.

Comment: Hi echo $SHELL gives me /bin/tcsh. But sed --version or sed -v doesn't work says unknown flag. I ran pkginfo -l SUNWcsu and it says 11.10.0

Comment: I am curious why you need to escape `:` in sed...

Answer (score 5):

```
echo 'this:is:a:test' | tr : \\n
```

Any [POSIX-compliant tr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/tr.html) will support the `\n` escape sequence.  You need to take care to quote or escape the escape sequence, however (double backslash above).

The `-e` argument to echo has no effect on your argument to echo.

Comment: +1 because this is the most lightweight solution. May not portable across ALL POSSIBLE shells. (one of my stupid busybox based shell doesn't have tr command itself...)

Comment: I wished it worked but no luck. Perl one works and creating variables and calling it works. This is probably an issue with my system. sigh.. Is there a way to update my commands such as? tr, grep, sed, etc...

Answer (score 4):

I'll presume that you have the string in a variable already. This uses the parameter expansion substitution operator to replace every `:` with a newline, which is specified using a `$'...'`-quoted string. Both features are `bash` extensions to the standard, and may not work in another shell.

```
$ foo="this:is:a:test"
$ bar="${foo//:/$'\n'}"
$ echo "$bar"
this
is
a
test
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `echo -e` because you have `\n` in `sed`, not in `echo` statement.
So, the following should work (note that I have changed `'\n'` to `\n`):

```
echo -e 'this:is:a:test' | sed "s/\:/\n/g"
```

or

```
echo  'this:is:a:test' | sed "s/\:/\n/g"
```

Also note that you do not need to escape `:` so the following will work too (thanks to @anishsane)

```
echo  'this:is:a:test' | sed "s/:/\n/g"
```

Below is just to reiterate why you need `-e` for `echo`

```
$ echo -e "hello \n"
hello

$ echo  "hello \n"
hello \n
```

Comment: you dont, it works without it...i was just using the code posted...will update the answer..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Perl is an option?

```
echo -e 'this:is:a:test' | perl -p -e 's/:/\n/g'
```

Comment: I'm not a perl fan but if you want consistent cross-platform search/replace actions than it's not such a bad method imho :) Especially when also using the `-i` (in-place) flag.

Answer (score 0):

If Python is an option:

```bash
echo 'this:is:a:test' | python3 -c 'print(input().replace(":", "\n"))'
```

output:

```
this
is
a
test
```

Answer (score 0):

If node js is an option you can use :

```
 node -e "console.log('this:is:a:test'.replaceAll(':','\n'))"
```

output

```
this
is
a
test
```

if you want to pass your $PATH just write

```
node -e "console.log('$PATH'.replaceAll(':','\n'))"
```

you can learn more about node -e or --eval option here [nodejs doc](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_e_eval_script)
and you can learn about the javascript replace all here [mdn web doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)