# Put all words separated by commas on a new line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am attempting to write a script to pull all words separated by commas on a new line from a text file that contains the following:

```
HELLO,DOCTOR,NAME,CONTINUE,YESTERDAY,TOMORROW
```

Comment: Note that you're generally expected to show your own work (what you tried, how it failed) when asking a question here.

Answer (score -1):

Demonstrating how to apply the individual linked-duplicate questions, each of which addresses a separate element of this question:

```
IFS=, read -r -a words <file  # from duplicate "How do I split a string on a delimiter?"
printf '%s\n' "${words[@]}"   # from duplicate "Print array elements on separate lines"
```

---

Similarly, the approach given in [How do I replace : characters with newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565487/how-do-i-replace-characters-with-newline) works just as well with `,` as with `:` --

```
tr ',' '\n' <file
```