# Bash: split line into multiple lines

Tags: bash, split

I have a list of words in lines:

```
aaaa bbbb ccc dddd
eee fff ggg hhh
iii jjj kkk
```

I want each word in a separate line:

```
aaaa
bbbb
ccc
dddd
eee
fff
ggg
hhh
iii
jjj
kkk
```

How to do that in bash with **least number of characters**? Without awk preferably.

Answer (score 22):

With pure bash:

```
while IFS=" " read -r -a line
do
    printf "%s\n" "${line[@]}"
done < file
```

See:

```
$ while IFS=" " read -r -a line; do printf "%s\n" "${line[@]}"; done < file
aaaa
bbbb
ccc
dddd
eee
fff
ggg
hhh
iii
jjj
kkk
```

With `xargs`:

```
xargs -n 1 < file
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' file
```

or

```
awk -v OFS="\n" '$1=$1' file
```

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/ /\n/g' file
```

With OS `sed`:

```
sed $'s/ /\\\n/g' file
```

With `cut`:

```
cut -d' ' --output-delimiter=$'\n' -f1- file
```

With `grep`:

```
grep -o '[^ ]\+' file
```

or

```
grep -Po '[^\s]+' file
```

Comment: Note that the xargs answer will not print any echo flags for example if the file contained `-e/E` or `-n` it will interpret that as an argument to the default echo for xargs.

Comment: `sed` example doesn't work for me, at least on MacOS. This worked instead `sed -e $'s/,/\\\n/g'` (found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18410122/4358405)

Comment: @TMG yes! In fact you don't need `-e`. Thanks for the info, I have updated my answer with it.

Comment: Why is the dollar sign necessary in the `--output-delimiter`? What does it do there?

Comment: @Asclepius because if we used `--output-delimiter='\n'` alone it will write a literal string "\n" instead of a new line. The dollar in `$'\n'` is used to tell the command to not treat the string literally.