# Find multiple strings between values and replace with newline in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, ip

I need to write a bash script to list values from an sql database.

I've got so far but now I need to get the rest of the way.

The string so far is

```
10.255.200.0/24";i:1;s:15:"10.255.207.0/24";i:2;s:14:"192.168.0.0/21
```

I now need to delete everything between the speech marks and send it to a new line.

desired output:

```
10.255.200.0/24
10.255.207.0/24
192.168.0.0/21
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ tr '"' '\n' <<< $string | awk 'NR%2'

10.255.200.0/24
10.255.207.0/24
192.168.0.0/21
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use :

```
echo 'INPUT STRING HERE' | sed $'s/"[^"]*"/\\\n/g'
```

Explanation :

- `sed 's/<PATTERN1>/<PATTERN2/g'` : we substitute every occurrence of `PATTERN1` by `PATTERN2`
- `[^"]*`: any character that is not a `"`, any number of time
- `\\\n`: syntax for newline in sed ([reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18410122/2057091))

Comment: or via here string: `sed $'s/"[^"]*"/\\\n/g' <<<'10.255.200.0/24";i:1;s:15:"10.255.207.0/24";i:2;s:14:"192.168.0.0/21'`

Comment: @RobC Indeed. I focused on the sed code in my answer rather than the input method

Comment: Whichever method is used (echo with pipe, or here string) the input string will need to be wrapped in single quotes and not double. The OP's string already contains non-escaped double quotes. So `echo 'INPUT STRING HERE' | ...` and not  `echo "INPUT STRING HERE" | ...` - as per current answer.

Comment: @RobC yup, that was an omission on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your Input_file is same as shown sample then could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\/[0-9]+/)){
    print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/"[^"]*"/\n/g' file
```

Or using along side Bash:

```
sed $'/"[^"]*"/\\n/g' file
```

Or using most other sed's:

```
sed ':a;/"[^"]*"\(.*\)\(.\|$\)/{G;s//\2\1/;ba}' file
```

This uses the feature that an unadulterated hold space contains a newline.