# Replace the contents between two lines specified by line numbers

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to replace the contents between two lines specified by line numbers using `bash`. For example. I have a file `sample.txt`, it has the following contents.

```
apple
peach
orange
juice
toy
computer
phone
```

I have a variable called var

```sh
var="cup\nbook"
```

I want to replace the contents between the second line and the 5th line(including the two lines) in `sample.txt` with the contents stored in `var`, so the final contents after the modification in file `sample.txt` should be

```
apple
cup
book
computer
phone
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `awk`:

```
var="cup\nbook"

awk -v var="$var" 'NR==2{print var} NR<2 || NR>5' file
```

```
apple
cup
book
computer
phone
```

---

Here is a `sed` solution that works with OSX sed (note definition of variable `var`):

```
var=$'cup\\\nbook'
sed "2,5c\\
$var
" file
```

```
apple
cup
book
computer
phone
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
var="cup\nbook"
sed "2,5c$var" file
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found that this command didn't work on macOS, is there any way to make it work on macOS?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748453/replace-comma-with-newline-in-sed-on-macos