# Private ssh key from one line environment var

Tags: unix, ssh-keys, bamboo

I have my privkey.pem private key in the form

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
xxx
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I need to make a Bamboo task to connect to a server via ssh using this key. Unfortunately I see that Bamboo can store only variables in one line, so if I paste the key all the "\n" get stripped out so this doesn't work:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
echo "${bamboo.sshKey}" | ssh-add - > /dev/null
scp -vvv -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no .....
```

Is there a way to have a private key in a "one line" format readable from ssh-add?
Or, is there a clean way to reparse the key to get again the stripped "\n"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know Bamboo. So possibly, there's a better solution. But one way would be to use some symbol to separate the lines in the variable. And then use something like `sed` or `tr` to convert the symbol to a new line, when feeding it to the `ssh-add`.

See [Replace comma with newline in sed on MacOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10748453/850848)

Answer (score 3):

I realize I am a bit late but solutions with `sed` and `tr` didn't work well for me. I ended up using `base64` and `base64 -d`, e.g.

First, convert your private SSH key on your Linux machine like this, into `base64` without any newlines:

```
 base64 ~/.ssh/yourkey.id_rsa | tr -d '\n'
```

Second, copy and paste that one line string into a new plan variable named "sshkey".

Finally, create a Script task that decodes the key and uses it.

```
echo "${bamboo.sshkey}" | base64 -d > id_rsa
chmod 600 id_rsa
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
....
rm id_rsa
```

Using a variable name like `sshkey` makes Bamboo mask it with `********` so it is somewhat casually obscured.  It's not secure, because you can unhide the value easily.

Be careful not to "edit' the `sshkey`, because if you edit the key and it shows `********` and then save it, the new key will literally be a bunch of asterisks. (not your fault, that's a UI failure)