# Is there a way to add a newline instead of commas in a CSV file?

Tags: csv, command-line, command

I have a CSV file. The contents are as follows:

```
1, 10, 10, 10, 11, 100, 10, 101, 100, 10, 110, 90, 111
```

Is there a Linux command to take each comma, delete it, and put a newline on the end? So it looks more like this:

```
1 
10 
10
10
11 
100 
10
101
100
10
110
90
111
```

Help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace comma with newline in sed on MacOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748453/replace-comma-with-newline-in-sed-on-macos)

Comment: @Alex No, thank you though. I am running Debian 10 Linux (Beta) on an HP Chromebook G14.

Comment: Debian also has `sed`. The link also has a solution using `try tr , '\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in Vim, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>, type `:%s/,/\r/g`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
This will replace all the commas in the file with new lines.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -F', ' 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"}{$1=$1}1' file
```

With `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/, /\n/g' file
```

Output:

```
1
10
10
10
11
100
10
101
100
10
110
90
111
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo '1, 10, 10, 10, 11, 100, 10, 101, 100, 10, 110, 90, 111' |
```

---

```
mawk $$ RS='[\7--]+'
```

---

```
1
10
10
10
11
100
10
101
100
10
110
90
111
```

you can even make them tier only when ever encountering more digits :

---

```
gawk NF=NF OFS='\f\t\b\b\b\b'
```

---

```
1,
    10, 
    10, 
    10, 
    11, 
    100,
            10, 
            101,
                    100,
                            10, 
                            110,
                                    90, 
                                    111
```