# How do I display a next line with sed under Jenkins Description?

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, sed, sh

I am trying to update the jenkins build description via running jenkins cli command under a script.

However I am trying to run the following command to change the description and display every line which is comma separated in `message1` variable as a new line in jenkins

I am running the following commands in my script to achieve this :

```
message2=$(echo  $message1  | sed 's/,/\n/g' )
   java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://JENKINS_INSTANCE:9090/ -auth user:token -webSocket set-build-description "$job" "$build" " <b style='color:green !important;'> $message2 <br> Message 2 supposed to be here<br>"
```

[image]

I am supposed to print the message2, message3 one after another in next line in jenkins.
Can someone please help me on how to achieve this ?

Comment: have you tried  tr , '\n' < file

Comment: check out  this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748453/replace-comma-with-newline-in-sed-on-macos

Comment: @rohitthomas yes I tried that. I don't know why I am able to run it on command line for testing but when I try it inside the script it is just not working with anything either tr or sed.

Comment: Try switching message1 with the actual message and test it out...

Comment: @rohitthomas I am gonna burst into tears now if it doesnt get solved :(
See , I have replaced it like this: 
`java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://JENKINS_INSTANCE/ -auth user:key -webSocket set-build-description "$job" "$build" "<b>$(echo  $message  | tr , '\n'  )</b>" ` Am I doing something wrong? can you suggest?

Comment: Any idea @rohitthomas ?

Comment: did you try the all the other options available ?

Comment: Almost tried every ans available in that question still had no luck and working on it

Comment: try awk or perl as a substitute