# How to append text to a file on a new line

Tags: groovy

Why does the following Groovy code not append the "**hello again**" on a new line?

```
f = new File('myfile.txt')
f.append('hello again!\n')
```

This adds to **myfile.txt** after the last line but not on a new line. How do I append the text on a new line?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should put the `\n` first. That way your newline will be written before your text:

```
f.append('\nhello again!')
```

Comment: I try it on groovy console , and I have the same problem!

Comment: Instead of '\n', have you tried using the line separator of your operating system, as per @MidoDev's answer ?

Comment: can you give example for that ?

Comment: f.append(System.getProperty("line.separator")+"hello again!")

Comment: the line separator is defined in system properties, it's not always "\n" maybe "\r\n" so in this case we your our system separator.

Comment: I think its not so good because now I run my first groovy script on xp machine and the next time it will be on other diff machine as win 2007

Comment: Just use the separator, it's always safe to do so, as opposed to \n

Comment: yes "\r\n" works but I need to run the groovy on other WIN type as WIN 2007 or vista , do you think the seperator will work there as it works on my win xp ????

Comment: If it works for XP, it will also work for any other Windows version.

Answer (score 12):

Yet another way of doing this. In this case, you don't have to add the newline character manually

```
File greetingsFile = new File("myfile.txt")
greetingsFile.withWriterAppend{ out ->
    out.println 'hello again!'
}
```

Comment: it does not append but re-write the entire file

Answer (score 10):

Groovy's concise syntax for writing into file:

```
f << '\n' << 'hello again'
```

Comment: Does this use a StringBuilder under the hood?

Comment: I think [it should be](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/IOGroovyMethods.html#leftShift(java.lang.Appendable,%20java.lang.Object)) equivalent to series of `f.append(..)` calls like this `f.append('\n'); f.append('hello again');`. So the answer is that some other sort of buffering implemented in `f` is used.

Answer (score 7):

You can always get the correct new line character through

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

so added it before your text

Comment: you mean to add the line "System.getProperty("line.separator")" before the line --> f.append('hello again!\n')    , ( sorry about the question I am very new in groovy )

Comment: f.append(System.getProperty("line.separator")" + 'hello again!\n')

Comment: If you are building a lot of strings, then you should probably do something like: def nl=System.getProperty("line.separator");  After that your code would look like: f.append("${nl}hello again!").  It would allow you to create a short pattern you could use in many output statements.