# Write to file with Jenkins and Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

When running my Jenkins build i need to update the contents of a file with a version number in this case. I have come across a plugin called `text-file-operations` but rather than write a whole new file I thought it would be better to update.

In this example I have a podspec file located in the root of the project which just needs a version number updated with a variable I have created earlier in the process.

```
spec.version               = '13.4.0'
```

I just need to convert that to

```
spec.version               = "${VERSION_NUMBER}"
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: So the file exists already with the content you specified last? Or is that what you want to write to the file, with the value from the environment variable?

Comment: the file already exists and i want to write to that file with the value of the environment variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want then?

[Groovy + how to append text in file ( new line )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410973/groovy-how-to-append-text-in-file-new-line)

```
f = new File('<filename>')
f.append("spec.version               = ${VERSION_NUMBER}\n")
```

Comment: it's almost what i require, seem to be having issues finding the file and permissions to access it.. would this replace the text or just append to the end of the file ?

Comment: It would append it. That is another issue, permissions and access, yes, the instance that runs the script (and with that user) has to be able to access the file.

Comment: ok thanks, can i just replace `spec.version = 'original value'` with `spec.version               = ${VERSION_NUMBER}\n`

Comment: Yes, unless you are doing something strange in your job. That should be enough. Please test it...