# Python carriage return and thread

Tags: python, multithreading, control-characters

So I have a script that will continuously read from a sensor, print a carriage return and then the sensor value. It does this until `raw_input()` finishes blocking (enter pressed).

However, when I run it, instead of an increasing number, I see blank space. When I press enter, one number is printed and then the program exits. If `\r` is replaced by `\n`, the program runs as it should, printing out the "sensor" value (`i = i + 1` is a placeholder for the reading of the sensor), but instead of reusing the same line it prints it on a new line.
Why does it not work with `\r`?
Here is the full code:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import sys

running = True

def loop():
        i = 0
        while running:
                sys.stdout.write("\r" + str(i))
                i = i+1
                sleep(0.1)


thread = Thread(target=loop)
thread.start()
raw_input()
running = False
thread.join()
```

Comment: Maybe you want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r

Comment: using `\r` it prints on consecutive lines and using `\n` it prints a newline as it should. What output do you expect to see?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham using `\r` on mine shows me nothing until i press enter, then I see one line and our closes. I should see at the beginning a single line that rewrites and increases, and stops when i press enter.

Comment: using `\r` I see `1True` etc.. I don't think you need the global keyword either.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sorry, i left those in from when i was testing the code. What does it do now I've edited it?

Comment: same, `0...` then a newline for `\n`  the output is on a single line for `\r`

Comment: @Padraig Cunningham i removed the `print running ` part.

Comment: I edited my comment, the output is the same minus the True, the difference is the `\r` output is on a single line

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the `\n` output i know works, does the `\r` output overwrite the same line or append it?

Comment: Which python are you using? I'm on 2.7

Comment: using python 2.7 on ubuntu 14.05, what os are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that writing out the newline flushes the channel, while writing out a carriage return (or most other character) doesn't. You can get the same behaviour by adding an explicit flush after the write():

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

As to *why* the lack of a flush causes the raw_input() to never return, I believe this is due to the buffering present on stdout; however, I've not been able to find more details.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying things and tried flushing the output with `sys.stdout.flush()` and it worked. Thank you all for your help.