# PHP "define" and escaped characters

Tags: php, constants

Is there a way to insert an escaped character for carriage return in a `define()` statement?

```
define('MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPALWPP_MARK_BUTTON_TXT', 
       "WSW uses PayPal as its primary merchant card account vendor./r
        You can check out with PayPal without the use of a PayPal account.");
```

I attempted the above statement but it will only out put the `/r` as literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `/r` to `\r` (**or** **`\n`** - [why see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r))

If you want to `echo` it, you can simply use `nl2br` function:

```
echo nl2br(MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPALWPP_MARK_BUTTON_TXT);
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know if I need another drink or sleep.

Comment: I'd go for the drink! :) Cheers! Feel free to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Unfortunately it only solved part of the issue. Now I can look at the source code and it shows the break but it is not being reflected on the actual page. Could that be due to a css setting?

Comment: Only thing I can imagine it's due to a css setting, when printing the line in a fresh page without any css appended it prints the line break.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will dig into the css.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use double quotes around the defined string - but use "\n" instead -- 
The "\n" and "\r" really only work when you are using the script via `php-cli` or some equivalent.

If you are rendering this in/`echo`ing to HTML, you'll have to use `<br>`

But, while you're at it, if you inspect the source via `Ctrl+U` or `view-source:` - then you'll see that your "\n" (I think "\r" may be the legacy version) - does, in fact appear as a line break.

Example:

```
echo "The quick brown fox <br> jumped over the lazy dog"; 
echo "The quick brown fox \n jumped over the lazy dog";
```

Try running that, and it'll make sense.

Comment: However, on inspecting the source the break is there and it is shown as a new line in the source but that is not being reflected on the actual page.

Comment: Exactly -!- You see, in the answer you accepted, the guy used `nl2br` which literally translates the `\n` to a `<br>` -- because in HTML, it will not break the line unless you tell it to... for the same reason that if you have a <p> tag, press enter a bunch of times, the browser still renders it all on the same line.