# carriage return in textarea retrieved as line feed

Tags: javascript, textarea, carriage-return

How can I preserve a carriage return character in a text area?

```
textarea.value = "X" + String.fromCharCode("13") + "X";
textarea.value.charCodeAt(1); //returns 10, not 13
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/vah9e/

Comment: Review this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r , I think you can use 10 instead of 13

Comment: This is unfortunate. It seems that there is no HTML element that will preserve user input for these types of characters. Suppose I was providing the user an input to search their data - I can't control their data. `\r` and `\n` may be meaningful to them.

Answer (score 1):

According to W3C [Textarea api value](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-textarea-element.html#concept-textarea-api-value), it seems that when invoking the `.value` attribute of `textarea`, any carriage return or line feed is transformed into a LINE FEED (10) character (in fact W3C says `CRFL` but it seems the browsers prefer only `LF`) - so a script can be platform-independent on line feeds.

In a form data, it seems that the fine feeds are transformed into `CRLF` (13+10).

W3C speaks also about a `raw value` but it's probably internal to any javascript engine and it seems it's not available in Javascript.