# Java + How to find a carriage return in a string value

Tags: java, string, carriage-return

How can I find a carriage return in a string value? I have implemented it following manner, but for long String values some times it may not works. Thanks.

```
String value = "carriage\n return\r\n in\n a\r\n string\n" 

for(String line : value.split("\n")) {
    if(line.contains("\r")) {
       System.out.println("Carriage return found");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly happens? Can you show an example of a long string with the unexpected result?

Answer (score 0):

Following this post : [Difference between \n and \r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r) I think you can do the split like that :

```
String value = "carriage\n return\r\n in\n a\r\n string\n";

    for (String line : value.split("\n|\r"))
        if (!line.trim().isEmpty())
            System.out.println("Carriage return found:" + line.trim());
```

Output :

```
Carriage return found:carriage
Carriage return found:return
Carriage return found:in
Carriage return found:a
Carriage return found:string
```