# Newline at the end of REST API value responses?

Tags: rest, express

I implemented a small REST API with [expressjs](http://expressjs.com) and once I provided it to my *users* (internal admin team) they asked to have an additional newline at the end of each response.

In code:

```
var app = require('express')();
app.get('/thing/id1', function (req, res) {
   res.send('data1');
})
```

vs:

```
app.get('/thing/id2', function (req, res) {
   res.send("data2\n");
})
```

The background is that in case they use the API via curl

```
$ > curl -s http://localhost:3000/thing/id1
data1$ >
```

They want to avoid the extra `echo` to have a nice output

```
$ > curl -s http://localhost:3000/thing/id1 ; echo
data1
$ >
```

I hate the additional newline in the code and it feels wrong to send it along, but I get the usecase.

So is there any argument, best practice or standard to follow in that regard?

Cheers.

Comment: "Nice output" is the responsibility of the presentation layer, not the API.

Comment: A proper shell (like `zsh` with the `PROMPT_CR` and `PROMPT_EOL_MARK` options) can be configured to handle this without the need to change your server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @PaulAbbott – your API should serve data, not presentation.

But you could also try `res.send("data2\n\r");`

Some prompts recognize `\n` as a newline, and others `\r`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1761086/922593