# How to remove line breaks inside a field in csv file?

Tags: csv, vim

I have a csv file that has line breaks inside fields like this :

```
"abc" , "adef
efw", "abc"
"abc","awe","abc"
```

Which should be :

```
"abc", "adefefw","abc"
"abc","awe","abc"
```

Does anyone know some tools or script to fix this ? I prefer using Vim.

Answer (score 5):

If all your fields are quoted with double quotes as in your example, you can simply remove all newline characters that follow a non-doublequote:

```
%s/\([^"]\)\n/\1/
```

For those looking for a non-interactive solution, `sed` is hard to work with when it comes to replacing newlines. Using perl, however, you can use the same expression as above:

```
perl -p -e 's/([^"])\n/\1/'
```

Comment: I was writing the exact same answer using sed, but you beat me to it. :-) FTR, on OSX, this works also: sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\([^"]\)\n/\1 /g' my_file.csv > fixed_file.csv

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an error on OS X (Catalina): 
sed: 1: "s/([^"])\n/\1 /g
": \1 not defined in the RE
Still searching for a command line version.

Comment: @Bjinse I added a non-interactive solution

Answer (score 0):

You have a carriage return or line break formatted in.
Show all character in your text editor (I use notepad++) and you should see:

```
\n or \r
```

\n is a line feed and \r is a carriage return, different systems use either one or both.

Simply move them where they should be.
[Differences of \n and \r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r)

Answer (score -3):

You may be able to use preg_replace() function with PHP but you would need to parse the CSV.

Another option might be to user the str_getcsv() function in PHP.

Example from page..

```
    <?php

    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));

    ?>
```

Once you parse it into an array you can then output it and reformat it how you would like.

Comment: going down the scripting route in this case is a little over kill as the person can do this in thir text editor. Vio can do this in a few key strokes.