# Python error in processing lines from a file

Tags: python, csv, utf

wrote a python script in windows 8.1 using Sublime Text editor and I just tried to run it from terminal in OSX Yosemite but I get an error.

My error occurs when parsing the first line of a .CSV file. This is the slice of the code
lines is an array where each element is the line in the file it is read from as a string
we split the string by the desired delimiter
we skip the first line because that is the header information (else condition)
For the last index in the for loop i = numlines -1 = the number of lines in the file - 2
We only add one to the value of i because the last line is blank in the file

```
for i in range(numlines):
    if i == numlines-1: 
        dataF = lines[i+1].split(',')
    else:
        dataF = lines[i+1].split(',') 
    dataF1 = list(dataF[3])
    del(dataF1[len(dataF1)-1])
    del(dataF1[len(dataF1)-1])
    del(dataF1[0])
    f[i] = ''.join(dataF1)
return f
```

All the lines in the csv file looks like this (with the exception of the header line):

```
"08/06/2015","19:00:00","1","410"
```

So it saves the single line into an array where each element corresponds to one of the 4 values separated by commas in a line of the CSV file. Then we take the 3 element in the array, "410" ,and create a list that should look like

```
['"','4','1','0','"','\n']
```

(and it does when run from windows)
but it instead looks like

```
['"','4','1','0','"','\r','\n']
```

and so when I concatenate this string based off the above code I get 410 instead of 410.

My question is: Where did the `'\r'` term come from? It is non-existent in the original files when ran by a windows machine. At first I thought it was the text format so I saved the CSV file to a UTF-8, that didn’t work. I tried changing the tab size from 4 to 8 spaces, that didn’t work. Running out of ideas now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between \n and \r?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r)

Comment: In my experience, I've found that files that were generated on a windows machine and loaded in *nix machine will create new lines using "\r\n" instead of "\n". No idea why though. You can get around it by replacing "\r" before dping the split though.

Comment: Open the file in text mode and it will make sure you only get `\n` across platforms. You're probably opening the file in binary mode `'b'` or similar.

Comment: The issue is I am trying to make the script OS independent and so i should be able to run it regardless of using Windows or Linux/Unix based systems.

Comment: According to python documentation open("filename.txt",'r') should open the file in text mode, accomdating an newline characters, and not binary mode. I am just confused as to why the '\r' appears on a unix based machine vs. windows based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"\r"` is the line separator. The `"\r\n"` is also a line separator. Different platforms have different line separators.

A simple fix: if you read a `line` from a file yourself, then `line.rstrip()` will remove the whitespace from the line end.

A proper fix: use [Python's standard CSV reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). It will skip the blank lines and comments, will properly handle quoted strings, etc.

Also, when working with long lists, it helps to stop thinking about them as index-addressed 'arrays' and use the 'stream' or 'sequential reading' metaphor.

So the typical way of handling a CSV file is something like:

```
import csv

with open('myfile.csv') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  # We assume that the file has 3 columns; adjust to taste
  for (first_field, second_field, third_field) in reader:
    # do something with field values of the current lines here
```