# PyCharm print end='\r' statement not working

Tags: python, pycharm

There are already lots of other questions about the print statement, but I have not found an answer to my problem:

When I do:

```
for idx in range(10):
    print(idx, end="\r")
```

in the (ipython) terminal directly, it works fine and always overwrites the previous line. However, when running this in a module with PyCharm, I don't see any lines printed in the stdout.

Is this a known PyCharm issue?

Comment: I don't think that you can rely on the behaviour of "\r".  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1761086/5568445

Comment: Have you tried flushing at the end? `print(..., flush=True)`

Comment: Intersting...but unfortunately it does not help me. Is there maybe another way how I can make this work in PyCharm
@tobias_k flush does not help ;)

Comment: I don't have PyCharm. Can you find out, what exact version of Python PyCharm is using? What does `import sys; print(sys.version)` show when run in PyCharm?

Comment: I am running Python 3.5.1 

Comment: I'm using PyCharm 2018.1 Community Edition on Windows 10 and a combination of the accepted answer _and_ `flush=True` worked for me.

Comment: Using PyCharm 2021.2 on Windows 10 with Python v3.9.2, what worked for me was including the `\r` at the beginning of each print string, and `end=''`.  I did not need to include `flush=True`.

Answer (score 35):

Try to add `\r` at the beginning of your printed string (not at the end):

```
for idx in range(10):
    print('\r', idx, end='')
```

Carriage return at front, and end with '' to avoid new line '\n'. One solution to avoid the space is to use the format convention:

```
for idx in range(10):
    print("'\r{0}".format(idx), end='')
```

Comment: YES! The first solution worked for me using PyCharm and Python3

Comment: for what it's worth, I coudn't get it to work for me.   Windows 7, Python 3.6.3, PyCharm 2017.2.4 community

Comment: Same issue in Spyder console. Adding the \r at the beginning of the string worked. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue.  While a solution using print() has eluded me, I have found sys.stdout.write works fine. (Win10, Python 3.5.1, Pycharm 2016.3.2)

```
import sys
import time

def countdown(n):
    for x in reversed(range(n)):
        sys.stdout.write('\r' + str(x))
        time.sleep(1)

countdown(60)
```

Comment: for what it's worth, I coudn't get it to work for me.   Windows 7, Python 3.6.3, PyCharm 2017.2.4 community