# Python sign loading, overwriting console line

Tags: python, ascii, loading

So I have this code and I have no idea how to run it in only one line by just overwriting the previous output if you know what I mean. Here is the code:

```
import time

signs = ["|", "/", "-", "\\"]
while True:
    for i in range(4):
         print("\r" + signs[i].format(i))
         time.sleep(1)
```

I would be very pleased if you could help me

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255147/how-do-i-keep-python-print-from-adding-newlines-or-spaces or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/python-multiple-prints-on-the-same-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `end='\r'` to your print statement, so this small change should do the job as you desired:

```py
import time

signs = ["|", "/", "-", "\\"]
while True:
    for i in range(4):
         print(signs[i].format(i), end='\r')
         time.sleep(1)
```

By default it is `\n` so next line symbol, but with `\r` (*carriage return*) the current line will be overwritten by the next output. 

It can cause problems though if the previous output is longer than the one following, then it does only overwrite as much characters as the new output has, the rest remains. In such cases it can help to add some whitespaces at the end of the output to fill the difference in sequence length. 
Generally the behaviour is dependent on the used *output* i.e. *Shell, Idle, writing to file, Eclipse, PyCharm* etc. Some output shells may not support this command.

Comment: @FredLarson Yes, they are equivalent as I see it.

Comment: @stanisławsłowiński Are you testing it in the shell? For me it works fine in Jupyter, shell should work also fine. It may be that some outputs, like logs do not support overwriting.

Comment: Im using Pycharm

Comment: It seems there can be issues with PyCharm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950201/pycharm-print-end-r-statement-not-working

Comment: Problem solved, for some reaseon it only works in the terminal. Thats totally fine for me. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @stanisławsłowiński Your welcome! Would be glad if you accept the answer!

Comment: I also found that Idle doesn't seem to honor the `'\r'`, Eclipse console seems to treat it just like `'\n'`, and I had to flush to see anything in my Linux Bash console.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately some output shells just don't process this command in a manner like - written is written! As said previously with log files it can be a problem too, because you cannot actually rewrite it. (As I know some readers are still able to simulate the desired behaviour on logs, I think `tail`
 does. So reading a log file with `\r` statements should work together with `tail -f`)

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
from __future__ import print_function # only needed for python 2.x
import time, sys

signs = ["|", "/", "-", "\\"]
while True:
    for i in range(4):
         print("\r" + signs[i].format(i), end="", flush=True)
         #print("\r" + signs[i].format(i), end="") # use this instead of above in python 2.x
         #sys.stdout.flush() # only needed for python 2.x
         time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I found that the future print_function in Python 2.7 [doesn't support `flush=True`](https://bugs.python.org/issue28458).

Comment: @FredLarson In this case you need `import sys` and then `sys.stdout.flush()` ... Thanks for pointing this out. I updated my answer accordingly!