# Ruby on Rails CSV Import rake task Fails Silently and does not import data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have tried to import a CSV file into ruby on rails using many scripts and methods and nothing seems to work. I have been hoping that code from Erik on Rails blog will help to get my job done.

I put this script into lib/tasks/import.rake:

```
desc "Imports a CSV file into an ActiveRecord table"
task :csv_model_import, [:filename, :model, :needs] => [:environment] do |task,args|
  lines = File.new(args[:filename]).readlines
  header = lines.shift.strip
  keys = header.split(',')
  lines.each do |line|
    values = line.strip.split(',')
    attributes = Hash[keys.zip values]
    Module.const_get(args[:model]).create(attributes)
  end
end
```

I created a model in the rails console

```
rails generate model SomeModel
```

then ran this in the rails console

```
rake csv_model_import[somefile.csv,SomeModel]
```

After running this, the cursor just returns in the console. It fails silently. When viewing the database file for the rails program, the table is empty after 
the import. It has filed to import the data.

I tried something else as well. I tried first creating a model with the fields and types defined before running the rake import command. This also failed in the same way.

I am very new to Ruby on Rails and I am. I have spent 2 days trying to get a CSV file into Ruby on Rails and would greatly appreciate some help. Please let me know how to proceed, Thanks so much guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on your approach and why you may not be getting anything:

When I tried to replicate the error, the following is what I found out:

> the line `lines = File.new(args[:filename]).readlines` reads the file in as one element separated by commas(,) for cells and new lines [(\r or \n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r) for new lines... e.g: `["name,age,food\rtabitha,2,carrots\relijah,1,lettuce\rbeatrice,3,apples"]`

This is the major problem because the blog post probably had another format gotten, on which the rest of the code is based on.

With this output, however... performing the shifting and splitting and stripping as above yields no result.

What I then did was to work off based on the result with the following steps:

1) Get the content:

```
file = File.new(args[:filename]).readlines => ["name,age,food\rtabitha,2,carrots\relijah,1,lettuce\rbeatrice,3,apples"]
```

2) Parse into a desired format by splitting on the new-lines (\r in my case)

```
lines = file.shift.strip.gsub(/\r/,"\\").split(/\\/) => ["name,age,food", "tabitha,2,carrots", "elijah,1,lettuce", "beatrice,3,apples"]
```

3) Get the headers:

```
header = lines.first => "name,age,food"
```

4) Get the body:

```
body = lines[1..-1] => ["tabitha,2,carrots", "elijah,1,lettuce", "beatrice,3,apples"]
```

5) Get keys from header:

```
keys = header.split(',') => ["name", "age", "food"]
```

6) Loop through the body and create objects in the database:

```
body.each do |line|
  values = line.strip.split(',')
  attributes = Hash[keys.zip values]
  Module.const_get(args[:model]).create(attributes)
end
```

The full gist is as follow:

```
desc "Imports a CSV file into an ActiveRecord table"
task :csv_model_import, [:filename, :model, :needs] => [:environment] do |task,args|
  file = File.new(args[:filename]).readlines
  lines = file.shift.strip.gsub(/\r/,"\\").split(/\\/)
  header = lines.first
  body = lines[1..-1]
  keys = header.split(',')
  body.each do |line|
    values = line.strip.split(',')
    attributes = Hash[keys.zip values]
    Module.const_get(args[:model]).create(attributes)
  end
end
```

PS: I notice the comment on ProgNoob's answer. you have to create a model first with all the needed attributes and have the database migrated. Then you can pass the model name and the csv file name into the rake file.

In my case, I have a model `Somemodel` generated as follow:

```
rails g model somemodel name:string age:string food:string
```

Notice that I added all the desired attributes.

And then migrated my database as:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

Comment: WOW, thanks so much for the help it works. For anyone trying to use this:

Comment: NOTES: generate the model first in the command prompt: rails g model somemodel name:string age:string food:string  (note the lower case s in somemodel) then copy the code block "full gist" into the lib/task and save it as import.rake then back in the command prompt type:  rake csv_model_import[directory/file.csv,Somemodel] (note the uppercase S in Somemodel this time.)