# How to detect if a newline is encountered in C++?

Tags: c++

I have input where we get to know that the current testcase has finished and next started by a blank line in between. How can I check that if a blank line has occurred in C++?

Comment: How are you reading the input?

Comment: By reading a line, and testing if it is a blank line... What issue are you having? How to read a line? How to test if it is blank? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're many ways to detect a blank line (if the line doesn't contain spaces, of course).

Example 1 (it's supposed you're getting your data line by line):

```
#include <string.h>

...

if (strcmp(yourLine, "") == 0) { // or strcmp(yourLine, "\n"), it depends how you get yourLine in your code above
    // your code
    ...
}
```

Example 2:

```
#include <string>

std::string yourData = "qwe\nrty\n\nasd\nfgh\n";

std::size_t index;
while ((index = yourData.find("\n\n")) != std::string::npos) {
    std::string part = yourData.substr(0, index);
    // your code
    yourData = yourData.substr(index);
}
```

In Example 2 methogs std::string::find and std::string::substr were used. You can look at the documentation for them: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Comment: Why even consider strcmp in C++?

Comment: It only works if you have valid NUL-terminated C string... And you really don't want to go there unless you have to interface with some C library or some such. Basically, it is an advanced and obscure topic from C++ point of view (and a major source of bugs in C).

Comment: if (strcmp(yourLine, "") == 0) will check if there is a new line ?

Comment: I get the input by getline(cin,s)

Comment: Then I'd recommend you to use (s.compare("") == 0), because the type of s is std::string. Or (strcmp(s.c_str(), "") == 0). Or (s.empty()). There're many ways to check, if you use getline, because this routine cuts '\n' symbol out.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check for '\r', '\n', or "\r\n" depending on what OS your code is running on. See [Difference between \n and \r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r) for a good explanation on why this is OS-dependent.