# Searched far and wide - still no solution to If statement error

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I am trying to see if a string in my array matches a word. If so, perform the If statement.

Sounds simple as pie but the If statement does not see the string from the array!

The array (temps) contains nothing but "non"s so I know it's something wrong with the If statment.

Here is the snippet of code:

```
    if ("non".equals(temps.get(3))) {
        System.out.println("Don't know.");
    }
```

Where temps is the array containing "non"s on different lines.

Here is the full code in case anyone is wondering:

```
public class Dump {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String token1 = "";

    //Reads in presidentsUSA.txt.
    Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("presidentsUSA.txt"));

    //Splits .txt file via new lines.
    inFile1.useDelimiter("\\n");

    List<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
      token1 = inFile1.next();
      temps.add(token1);
    }
    inFile1.close();

    // Stores each new line into an array called temps.
    String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);

        if ("non".equals(temps.get(3))) {
            System.out.println("Don't know.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a greate example where you can make yourself farmilar with the debugger.

Comment: Try printing out temps.get(3) and temps.get(3).length().  You might find it is not exactly what you want.  Using temps.get(3).startsWith("non") might fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable explanation why your if statement returns false is that you are on a Windows OS.

If you debug your code and watch `temps.get(3)` it will show the content as

> non\r

and non\r does not equal non

Solution:

```
inFile1.useDelimiter("\\r\\n");
```

Check the accepted answere here (especially point 4): [Difference between \n and \r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r?lq=1)

Comment: Absolutely smashing. Thanks Moh-Aw!