# Add line break in title in ReporteRs

Tags: r, newline, reporters

In this example, I would like to put a line break between "Episode IV" and "A New Hope" but `\n` isn't working... how can I do it?

```
library("ReporteRs")
deck <- pptx( title = "Star Wars Movies")  
deck <- addSlide( deck, slide.layout = "Title and Content" )
deck <- addTitle( deck, "Episode IV\nA New Hope")
# spoiler alert
deck <- addParagraph(deck, paste("This movie is about Luke Skywalker, Han Solo,",
                                 "Obi-Wan Kenobi, and some droids who rescue",
                                 "Princess Leia and blow up the Death Star.") )
writeDoc(deck, file = "temp.pptx" )
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\r\n` instead of `\n` only

```
library("ReporteRs")
deck <- pptx( title = "Star Wars Movies")  
deck <- addSlide( deck, slide.layout = "Title and Content" )
deck <- addTitle( deck, "Episode IV\r\nA New Hope")
# spoiler alert
deck <- addParagraph(deck, paste("This movie is about Luke Skywalker, Han Solo,",
                                 "Obi-Wan Kenobi, and some droids who rescue",
                                 "Princess Leia and blow up the Death Star.") )
writeDoc(deck, file = "temp.pptx" )
```

Comment: Good old Microsoft.  Forgot I was writing to a powerpoint, not a text file.  `\r\n` it is.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1761086/2573061) for the difference.  Thanks.