# How can I use the output of a JavaScript function as a string inside a HTML textarea box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been creating a profile making program and I would like to use the output of this JS function as a simple string text inside the textarea box which the user can copy using the "Copy to Clipboard" button. Any ideas, please let me know ASAP. Here is my current code:

```
<!--HTML-->
<!--Button Code-->
<button onclick="copyprofile()">Copy to clipboard</button><br>   
<!--Textarea Code-->
<textarea id="text" cols="60" rows="13">I want output of createProfile() to be here</textarea><br>

//Javascript
function createProfile(){
    var fn,ln,a,fc,fs,ff,profile;
    fn = prompt("Please enter your first name","Enter first name here");
    ln = prompt("Please enter your last name","Enter last name here");
    a = prompt ("Please enter your age","Enter age here");
    fc = prompt("Please enter your favourite colour","Enter favourite color here");     
    fs = prompt("Please enter your favourite sport","Enter favourite sport here");
    ff = prompt("Please enter your favourite food","Enter favourite food here");
    profile = ("Name: " + fn + " " + ln + "<br>Age: " + a + "<br>Favourite colour: " + fc + "<br>Favourite sport: " + fs + "<br>Favourite food: " + ff);
    return profile;
}
function copyProfile(){
    var text = document.getElementById('text');
    var range = document.createrange();

    range.selectNode(text);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand(copy);
}
```

If you have any thoughts or ideas on how to achieve this, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being that you have already saved everything in a string assigned to `profile`, just reference the element you want to update and assign it as the `value`.

In javascript:

```
document.getElementById("text").value = profile;
```

And if you want the to keep the line breaks, you'll need to do something other than `<br>` as a `textarea` doesn't typically render HTML. I'd suggest doing a [carriage return or line feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r). `\n`

```
profile =  ("Name: " + fn + " " + ln + "\nAge: " + a + "\nFavourite colour: " + fc + "\nFavourite sport: " + fs + "\nFavourite food: " + ff);;
```

Here is a JSFiddle with an example https://jsfiddle.net/x1w1t8ux/

---

**Update**

I took some time to look at the rest of your code as you said it still was not working as you expected. Your `copyProfile` function has a couple of errors. If you open up your developer console when trying to run these functions, you'll see the error messages:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.createrange is not a function

You're line `document.createrange()` is not a function. You need to camel case it to be [`document.createRange()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createRange).

After you fix that error, try to run the code again will display another error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: copy is not defined

In this line `document.execCommand(copy);` you are referencing a variable called `copy`. That variable does not exist, nor is it what you're looking for. You are wanting to pass the string *copy* to the function [`execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand). It should look like `document.execCommand('copy');` (with quotes, as that's how you identify a string in JavaScript.

In your HTML, when you click on your Copy To Clipboard button `<button onclick="copyProfile()">Copy to clipboard</button>` it throws an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: copyprofile is not defined

You do not have a function called `copyprofile`, you have one called `copyProfile`. Function names are case sensitive. I would recommend sticking to a consistent naming convention (such as camel case)

Lastly, no where in your code are you calling the function `createProfile()`. So I created it as a second button in my testing.

Comment: Thanks mate. Appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem. if it solved your problem, go ahead and mark as accepted answer to help others in the future as well.

Comment: Hi mate, just wondering if you have any idea of what to put inside the actual <textarea> tag as I am not sure how to use the code that you have given me. In other words, where and how should I use your code.

Comment: Sorry, I am a new programmer and this is how I am trying to run my code: I have been trying to use:                  profile = ("Name: " + fn + " " + ln + "\nAge: " + a + "\nFavourite colour: " + fc + "\nFavourite sport: " + fs + "\nFavourite food: " + ff);
   document.getElementById('text').value return: profile; <pre> <code>            But this has not been working. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you're missing assigning `profile` to the element's `value`. `document.getElementById("text").value = profile;`

Comment: Cheers again Enigma. Just what I was looking for. You are a genius. Thanks again 

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the user inputting their profile info from a prompt rather than the input being fixed in the text editor by the creator? If so, please let me know

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. Are you referring to the example I provided in jsfiddle? I hardcoded those values for testing so that I wouldn't have to go through the process of answering everything. You can continue to use your existing code. The original answer I gave you was intended to be added to your existing code...

Comment: Sorry for any confusion caused. The code provided in this link: http://postimg.org/image/7w6duuizf/ was not working so just wondering if you could help. Thanks

Comment: But what specifically is not working? Are you getting errors in your console? Is the copy to clipboard not working? is the user input not being displayed in the `textarea`?

Comment: You're in luck. I took the time to troubleshoot your other function. FYI, typically this requires asking a new question. Not just asking for additional help in the comments.

Comment: I'm also going to add, make sure you're taking the time to understand what this code is doing. It appears that you're copying & pasting others' answers.

Comment: The actual prompts are not appearing to ask the user their profile inputs.

Comment: See my updated answer. It's because no where are you calling the function `createProfile()`. Add another button to call it.

Comment: Do you mean create another button to call `createProfile()` as in this?: `<button onClick="createProfile());">Start profile creator</button><br>`

Comment: Also what should I set my var `copy` equal to?

Comment: Did you read the link I posted for `execCommand()`? You are supposed to pass in the string copy. `execCommand('copy')`.

Comment: I have literally given you step-by-step instructions that you can copy and paste to get your code working. Just take the time to read what has been posted in it's entirety!

Comment: Thanks so so much Mr Enigma. The code worked perfectly after thoroughly researching and understanding this subject. I have now styled it and added more questions and all the code is working perfectly. You can see how it looks if you like by copying code from http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/5950. Thanks again :)