# Need help creating a php program that echoes code

Tags: php, html

I am creating a program that is supposed to take a code input from the user and it will match it with some other sample code, and once it is done it will print the users input code. The part that I am having trouble with is when I print the users code, everything is printed but instead of indents and line breaks, this is being printed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n <script src=\"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js\" integrity=\"sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0=\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>\r\n<html>\r\n <head>\r\n <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\r\n <title>CodeType</title>\r\n   </head>\r\n <body>
```

whereas this is the input (and what I want as the final result):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<html>
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <title>CodeType</title>
     </head>
   <body>
```

Here is my code:

```
        <?php include "database.php"; ?>
        <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['title']);
        $code =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['code']);
        $samplecode = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['samplecode']);

        $query = "INSERT INTO `assignments` (`title`, `code`) VALUES ('$title', '$code')";

        $cleanCode = str_replace( "\r\n", "<br/>" , htmlentities($code));
        if(mysqli_query($con, $query)){
            if($code = $samplecode){
                echo $cleanCode;
            }
        } else {
            echo "fails";
        }
    }

   ?>

    <body>

    <br/>
        <form method = "post" action = "">
            <label id = "title">Title</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="text" class="txtInput" name = "title"/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <label id = "stuff">Code</label>
            <br/>
            <textarea placeholder="Type your code in here" name = "code"></textarea>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <label id = "samplecode">Sample testing</label>
            <br/>
            <textarea placeholder="Type your test code in here" name = "samplecode"></textarea>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Submit"/>

            <pre><?php echo $cleanCode ?></pre> 
        </form>

    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.txtInput').bind("paste",function(e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
            });
            $( "button" ).on( "click", function(){
                if($(#txtInput).text() == $(#code).text()){
                    alert("Working");
                } else {
                    alert("Failure");
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In that top block of code, are the `\r\n`s literally there?

Comment: Yes, the \r\n s are actually there

Comment: Try this: change `$cleanCode = str_replace( "\r\n", "<br/>" , htmlentities($code));` to this `$cleanCode = str_replace( "\n", "<br/>" , htmlentities($_POST['code']));`

Comment: Thanks! That worked out perfectly!

Comment: If you get the chance (and I was a help to you), I'd appreciate if you accepted my answer. :D  (It will also alert other people to the fact that this question is solved.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Background Info:**

1. Like C, PHP *presumably* (said that way because I haven't found a reference for it yet...) converts `\r\n` / `\n` to just an `\n`.
   (Different sequences are used for a newline depending on [the OS.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r))
2. `mysqli_real_escape_string()` [escapes `\r` and `\n`, among others](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

---

**What that means:**

- We don't need to replace `\r\n`; rather, we should replace `\n`.
- Since `mysqli_real_escape_string()` escapes our newline characters, we need to use `$_POST['code'];` for anything that is not database related.

---

**TL;DR**

```
$cleanCode = str_replace( "\r\n", "<br/>" , htmlentities($code));
```

*should be:*

```
$cleanCode = str_replace( "\n", "<br/>" , htmlentities($_POST['code']));
```

Comment: I have used your code snippet, but I still get the same problem. Any other suggestions?