# How to remove/replace \r from my text file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filereader

I have to take the first line from my text file and compare to the values from my array. I'm using `new FileReader()` to get the first line from my .txt file. Here is my code:

```
var fileExist = $('#fileUpload')[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
var file = fileExist.files[0];
reader.onload = function(e) {
    var text = reader.result;                 
    var firstLine = text.split('\n').shift(); 
    var columnNames = firstLine.split('\t');

    console.log(columnNames);
}
reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');
```

Here is my output:

```
["LAST_NAME", "FIRST_NAME", "BIRTH_DATE", "GENDER",  "PHONE", "EMAIL\r"]
```

For some reason my last element in the array has `\r`. This is the case with any text file that i try to load with this function. How I can get rid of `\r` ? I tried to include in my split function \r but that did not work, first it looks that all comma's were removed and there is no `[]` brackets around the text. If anyone can help with this problem please let me know. My text file is tab delimited.

Comment: `text.split(/\r\n|\n/)...`

Comment: @Teemu I tried and works fine with the code that you provided. What is a difference and what is actually \r ? Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r

Comment: Is there a way how I can check everything but the first line from my .txt file? Do I have to use .slice() for that or something else?

Comment: Like so: `text=reader.result.split(/\r\n|\n/); firstLine=text.shift();` This way the first line is pulled into its own variable, and the rest of the content will be in the `text` array.