# How to replace a new line character in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, ascii

Hi =)  I have some code that I am struggling with.  I have a function to replace specific html characters values like a tab or new line, however it doesn't seem to work very well.

```
var replaceHTMLCharacters = function(text){
  text = text.split("");
    for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
        if(text[i].charCodeAt(0) == 10){
            text[i] = "\n";
        }
    }
  text = text.join("");
  console.log(text);
  return text;
}
```

This is an example of me trying to remove a new line character and replace it with "\n" so that I can store it in a JSON format.  It reaches the point where it says `text[i] = "\n"` but then doesn't actually set this character to a `"\n"`.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thank you.

Comment: Have you try \r\n ?

Comment: "\n" *is* a newline character. You're replacing them with what's already there, leaving the String unchanged. If you want the actual characters \ and n, you need to mask the backslash "\\n" and insert that.

Comment: @ChrisG Ah yes that did the trick for me thank you.  Post as answer I will mark as solution

Comment: Why do you need to do this to store in JSON? `JSON.stringify()` will do this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"\n" is a newline character. You're replacing them with what's already there, leaving the String unchanged. If you want the actual characters \ and n, you need to mask the backslash `\\n` and insert that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off using a bit of regex here. Try this code (I also purposely renamed your function to have a bit more describing name):

```
function breakOnTab (string) {
    return string.replace(/\t/g, '\r\n')
}
```

This regex finds all tab characters `\t` and replaces them with a string consisting of escaped carriage return and new line.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are replacing "\n" with "\n". To replace '\n' you will need to escape it by adding an additional '\' or '\n'

Answer (score 0):

First of all: HTML chars do not exist...

Second: I don't understand why you did `text = text.split("");`, you will iterate over an array instead of an String, spending time and memory...

Third: '\n' charCode is 10...

If you want to rewrite text formatted on HTML to plain text, you could  do something like:

```
var replaceHTMLCharacters = function(text){
  text = text.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/g,'\n');
  console.log(text);
  return text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this with \n and \t ..

You could check also checkout [Difference between \n and \r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r)

```js
var replaceHTMLCharacters = function(text) {
  var reg = new RegExp(/(\r\n?|\n|\t)/g);
  var ntext = text.replace(reg, "-");
  console.log(ntext);
  return text;
}

replaceHTMLCharacters(`newLine
Text1`)
replaceHTMLCharacters("Tab text2");
```