# How to deal with carriage return that concatenate strings at the end and beginning of a line?

Tags: java, arrays, carriage-return

I have a text file with 2 lines of words

```
CCCCC,WIKY PODAR,130000,15
DDDDD,XXXXX555,130110,30
```

Program reads each line word by word spilt and store them into an array.

check myStringArray.length returns : 7

However I expect the output to be  : 8

The issue is that two words at the end and the begining of the line are concatenated. How to seperate them and store into the array properly ?

```
 String fileName = "mac/text.txt";
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
     while (inputStream.read(buffer) != -1) {
        String testString2 = new String(buffer);
        String delim2 = ",";
        String[] token2 = testString2.split(delim2);
        String[] myStringArray = new String[token2.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < token2.length; i++) {
            myStringArray[i] = token2[i];
             token2[i]=token2[i].replaceAll("\\s+", ", ");
                            }
        System.out.println(myStringArray.length);
```

Comment: one approach is read one line then tokenize it , read next line then again tokenize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not load all the content in a String and replace in the String the line separator String by the `","` character ? Then you can easily split the String with a single separator `","`.

You can try it :

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("mac/text.txt")));
content = content.replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), ",");
String[] token2 = content.split(",");
```

Or if you want to avoid a call to replaceAll() and perform directly a split you can indicate in the regex the `,` character `OR` the line separator string :

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("mac/text.txt")));
String[] token2 = content.split(",|"+System.lineSeparator());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should to split your String with two delimiters like this :

```
//delimiters with two separator , and space
String delim2 = ",|\\ ";
String testString2 = "CCCCC,WIKY PODAR,130000,15\n" +
                     "DDDDD,XXXXX555,130110,30";
String[] token2 = testString2.split(delim2);
System.out.println(token2.length);
```

This should `8` instead to `7`, because we use two delimiters `,` and `space`.

**EDIT**

ok this is another way to learn from your file and split it :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    //path of your file
    String fileName = "mac/text.txt";
    //read your String from your file like this :
    String input = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));
    System.out.println(input);

    String delim = ",|\\ ";
    String[] token = input.split(delim);
    System.out.println(token.length);
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering , but the length is still 7, i read the words from a text file .

Comment: can you print what your already read, because if you set this String so you will get 8 and not 7, maybe your text is diffirent so after you read your text print it @Snailwalker

Comment: @Snailwalker i edit my answer hope this can work for you, i makes another way to read your String from file good luck

Answer (score 1):

the first line will end with a line-delimiter (which is different per operating system): see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1761086/6287240) for more details

so if it should work for Windows, Linux and Mac files you may want to replace the line-delimiter with a comma first and then split the rest like this:

```
testString = testString.replaceAll("\r\n", ",").replaceAll("\r", ",").replaceAll("\n", ",");
// now your string looks like this: CCCCC,WIKY PODAR,130000,15,DDDDD,XXXXX555,130110,30
String[] token2 = testString.split(",");
```

Comment: Hey. this regx seems work. but there is a comma between WIKY and PODAR.

Comment: what do you mean? there is a space between WIKY and PODAR. If you want  to also replace spaces, just add a replaceAll call. or if you want to replace all whitespace (incl. tabs), you can replace the whole line with this: `testString = testString.replaceAll("\\s", ",");`

Comment: I mean my program outputs an extra comma in that space. It shouldn't be there though. Thank you.