# C# get exact string from Mysql not working

Tags: c#, mysql, string, mysqldatareader

I have problems with a MySQL data using C#. The string data in the database is a multiline text, I mean, with the " **\n** ". So I want to show it in a multiline texbox but it shows me everything in one line.

For example: the string in the database is: 
[PICTURE OF THE DATABASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gl8Y.png)

"1

2"

But at the time of getting the data with the datareader and display it in a textbox in C # shows me: [PICTURE OF THE PROGRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPndm.png)

"1 2"

**So how can i display it in separate lines? i mean, using the same format as in the database.**

Comment: Have you debugged the actual's string content using a breakpoint? What kind of textbox are you using? In `winforms` there is a property to make it multiline

Comment: yes, the textbox is set on MultiLine. I will check the breakpoint and see what happend in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\r\n is the proper line ending for windows, so try replacing \n with \r\n and see if the output displays correctly.

```
var test= mystring.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
mytextbox.Text = test;
```

[Difference between \n and \r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r)

Answer (score 0):

Your Textbox just doesn't like the `"\n"` as new line. You can either replace it with `"\r\n"` or `Environment.NewLine` by:

```
YourMultiLineString = YourMultiLineString.Replace('\n", Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: yes it is. I tried to display it in the Result Console, and it shows in differents lines, so i think is a problem with the textbox :c

Comment: suffuko, can you run the following fuction, YourMultiLineString.Split(Environment.NewLine); , and tell me the size of the result array?

Comment: suffuko, you can also try  YourMultiLineString = YourMultiLineString.Replace('\n", Environment.NewLine); and see how that looks in the textbox