# Adding suffix to every line [PHP and textarea HTML]

Tags: php, html, suffix

Greets
Is it possible to add suffix to every line from textarea using PHP?
I know we can get text from textarea to Variables and then? How to add enter- (new line) as variable?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](https://i.imgsafe.org/c457c15b1f.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
<form method="GET">
<textarea name="inputFromTextArea">This is line 1
This is line 2
...
This is line 4</textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php 

/* Convert text with lines to an array (\r\n = Carriage return & Newline on Windows machines*/
$lines = explode("\n", $_GET['inputFromTextArea']);

/* debug information to show the contents of $lines */
echo "<pre>";
print_r($lines);
echo "</pre>";

/* Loop over all lines and manipulate each line */
foreach($lines as $lineNr => $line){
    $lines[$lineNr] = trim($line,"\r") . " a suffix here "; // remove possible Carriage returns & concatenate stuff
}

/* debug information to show the contents of $lines */
echo "<pre>";
print_r($lines);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Read more on Carriage return & Newlines here: \r\n = [Difference between \n and \r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r)

Comment: When in doubt explode on `\n` and `ltrim($text,"\r")`.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I have a problem, because for me it doesn't work. I created <textarea name="inputFromTextArea" with <form method="get"> 
and in second textarea, where this PHP code is, nothing happens.

Comment: I would like to ask if there exist any other function to output a string without [n] =>?

Comment: replace it with nothing like this:str_replace("\n", "", $targetString); It replaces \n with nothing (empty brackets as 2nd parameter)

Comment: I suppose, \n means new line. I had used str_replace but, nothing changed. I just want to delete numbers [0] => hello
    [1] => world

Comment: I need more info, you want to remove the KEY items from an array value or what do you mean?