# What does VxWorks use for a newline character?

Tags: newline, stdio, vxworks

**tl;dr**

What does VxWorks use for a newline in a terminal (console) application?

**Background**

I am trying to work out what newline sequence is expected by vxWorks (e.g. std::endl or similar mechanisms).  Of course, Windows uses "\r\n", Linux uses "\n", with a laundry list of OS implementations listed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) ... except VxWorks! Nor [is](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/tyLib.html) [the](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/fioLib.html) [documentation](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/guide/c-iosys.html) very clear on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Newline character is "\n", as it is in most OSes, You can run the following code to check yourself.

```
#include "vxWorks.h"
#include "stdio.h"

void start(void) {

 printf("First Line:\n");
 printf("Second Line:\n");
 printf("Fourth Line:");
 printf("Fifth Line:\n");
 printf("Sixth  Line:\n");

}
```

If you load and run the above module(if running in kernel mode), you will get out put as:-

```
-> ld < so.out
->value = 944654968 = 0x384e4a78 = 'x'
-> start
First Line:
Second Line:
Fourth Line:Fifth Line:
Sixth  Line:
value = 10 = 0xa
->
```

Edit: text segment of the dkm

```
[vxWorks *]# module 

MODULE NAME     MODULE ID  GROUP #    TEXT START DATA START  BSS START
--------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
so.out          0x384f7aa8          2 0x10640000 NO SEGMENT 0x10650000
[vxWorks *]# d 0x10640000
NOTE: memory values are displayed in hexadecimal.
0x10640000:  8955 83e5 18ec 04c7 4424 6400 e810 48ee  *U.......$D.d...H*
0x10640010:  ffb4 04c7 5024 6400 e810 48e2 ffb4 04c7  *....$P.d...H....*
0x10640020:  5d24 6400 e810 d196 ffb7 04c7 6a24 6400  *$].d........$j.d*
0x10640030:  e810 48ca ffb4 04c7 7624 6400 e810 48be  *...H....$v.d...H*
0x10640040:  ffb4 c3c9 6946 7372 2074 694c 656e 003a  *....First Line:.*
0x10640050:  6553 6f63 646e 4c20 6e69 3a65 4600 756f  *Second Line:.Fou*
0x10640060:  7472 2068 694c 656e 003a 6946 7466 2068  *rth Line:.Fifth *
0x10640070:  694c 656e 003a 6953 7478 2068 4c20 6e69  *Line:.Sixth  Lin*
0x10640080:  3a65 0000 0014 0000 0000 0000 7a01 0052  *e:...........zR.*
0x10640090:  7c01 0108 0c1b 0404 0188 0000 001c 0000  *.|..............*
0x106400a0:  001c 0000 ff5c ffff 0044 0000 4100 080e  *....\...D....A..*
0x106400b0:  0285 0d42 0205 c540 040c 0004 0000 0000  *..B...@.........*
0x106400c0:  6174 2067 4d53 2050 0030 6e65 0064 0000  *tag SMP 0.end...*
0x106400d0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  *................*
0x106400e0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  *................*
0x106400f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  *................*
[vxWorks *]#
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I don't have a VxWorks platform to test with, but could you please confirm with a "hexdump" utility. For example, under Linux it would be ./start | hexdump -c and we will be able to see which characters make it to the console.  Some OS (e.g. Windows) will silently translate the "\n" to "\r\n" when writing to the console.

Comment: I am not sure about hexdump or relevant utility in VxWorks, but if it helps, I am appending to the answer, the text segment of the kernel module

Comment: Unfortunately, the text of the module isn't helpful.  The character stream of the output of the program is.

Comment: I think \n\r is only relevant to windows. Since VxWorks is POSIX compliant , I assume it wouldnt be any different than linux. You may also want to check this discussion  , If you have not checked it already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r[link]