# solr highlighting snippet by newline

Tags: regex, solr, newline, code-snippets, highlighting

I am using solr and need to get the highlighting results in separated snippets by newlines. For example, searching "scores" using this text:

```
Algebra:
My scores are:
A, A+, B, B, A

Calculus:
My scores are:
B, A, A, A+, B
```

I want to get in one snippet:

```
Algebra:
My <em>scores</em> are:
A, A+, B, B, A
```

And in another snippet:

```
Calculus:
My <em>scores</em> are:
B, A, A, A+, B
```

The full result use 2 newlines (\n \n) as splitter, so I tried using `hl.fragmenter=regex&hl.regex.pattern=[%0A%20%0A]` to separate them. However the snippets are not being splitted by this pattern.

I would like to split text in snippets regardless the size of the text between the 2 newlines.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that in addition to the newline there is a carriage return as well, see: [Difference between \n and \r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r).

You can try using this regex that will take that into account:

```
/\r?\n\r?\n/
```