# UWP TextBox control giving unexpected results

Tags: c#, textbox, uwp

Simple Text Editor

With TextBox AcceptsReturn property checked saving multiline contents of a text box to a text file results all text written in single line only when opened in notepad. It opens fine when file is loaded in UWP TextBox control. I don't have this problem with old WPF TextBox control.

My program has two buttons, open and save. In between there is text box.

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
using Windows.Storage;

// ...
    StorageFile selectedFile;

    private async void openFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        contentsTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
        addressText.Text = string.Empty;
        selectedFile = null;

        FileOpenPicker openDialog = new FileOpenPicker();
        openDialog.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        selectedFile = await openDialog.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (selectedFile != null)
        {
            addressText.Text = selectedFile.Path;

            try
            {
                contentsTextBox.Text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(selectedFile);
            }

            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) { } // In case file is empty
        }
    }

    private async void saveFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (selectedFile != null)
        {
            await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(selectedFile, contentsTextBox.Text);
            await new MessageDialog("Changes saved!").ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the box also set to multi line?   In Win32 you need both.

Comment: There is no multi line option in properties window of text box

Comment: openDialog.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");    break

Comment: ..........what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the TextBox's Text property, an end-of-line is represented by `\r`. However, notepad expects `\r\n` for a line break.

For more information on the differences between the two (and other variants), [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051).

Just replace "\r" to "\r\n" before saving the text to file.

```
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(selectedFile, contentsTextBox.Text.Replace("\r", "\r\n"));
```

Comment: Environment Newline