# UWP application not reading line feed

Tags: c#, uwp, newline, linefeed

I am creating a C# UWP application and I have noticed that the line feed (\n) character is missing from the output text when I enter it into a Textbox.  When I press enter into my Textbox it produces CR+LF character (\r\n).  what can I do to bring the textbox behavior to notice both CR+LF & LF.  I have set AcceptReturn = "true" and I have even tried replacing \n with \r\n but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  what does it mean to have the textbox notice LF?  how will you get LF into the textbox? if you press Enter you will always get a CRLF

Comment: I want my textbox to get LF not just CRLF.  Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: New textBox use `\r`

Answer (score 0):

As @lindexi said the new `TextBox` used `\r` as line feed character in  Windows 10 build 15063. If you want to bring the textbox behavior to notice both CR+LF & LF. You may handle it programmatically on KeyUp event. However the `\n` & `\n\r` will turn to `\r` automatically.

For example :

```
// original
MyTextBox.Text = "Nico Zhu \nzhuminghao\nwanglaoshi\r\n\rzhuzhuz\n";

// converted
MyTextBox.Text = "Nico Zhu \rzhuminghao\rwanglaoshi\r\rzhuzhuz\r"
```

For more please refer to [UWP TextBox control giving unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44339045/uwp-textbox-control-giving-unexpected-results).

Comment: Do you think if I reinstall an earlier form of windows, like Windows 8, that it will make my TextBox use \n and \r as line feed characters rather than just \r.  Because I need the application to be able to read the \n character as line feed character.  however as it stands now, the \n is being filtered out of my TextBox as it gets typed in.

Comment: This is super inconvenient: now the text entered in my UWP app looks different in my Xamarin iOS and Android app depending on the Windows version it was entered in, how on earth will I fix this...