# text from barcode scanner being filtered out when entered into UWP textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, uwp, barcode-scanner

I am developing an app which reads the info from a barcode scanner then parses the information.

when I scan the information into a text box the '\n' line feed character is being filtered out from the textbox.  I have made accept returns = true but in still getting the same issue.

when I scan the information into notepad I am getting the \n line feed character so I know it is present.  I also get \r\n which are different from the line feeds which my application is able to read.

my question is, how can I make the text box accept line feeds

Comment: You have to provide at least your code and the model of the Barcode scanner so that People here could help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP application not reading line feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723118/uwp-application-not-reading-line-feed).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. The Windows `TextBox` only accepts `\r\n` as line breaks. `\n` will be ignored.

To represent a new line for each `\n` character, you'll have to replace it with the Windows representation of a new line.

```
var input = GetInputFromScanner();
var cleanInput = input.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
// Assign "cleanInput" to your "TextBox" instance
```