# no carriage return while using dlmwrite( ) to write array values to file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, carriage-return

I am trying to write the array values to CSV file in MATLAB using the following code

```
m=[3 12 15 ; 4 23 565];
dlmwrite('C:\Users\amar-admin\Desktop\abc.txt', m)
type C:\Users\amar-admin\Desktop\abc.txt
```

the output printed in the console is

```
3,12,15
4,23,565
```

but the output in File is

```
3,12,154,23,565
```

Comment: I can't reproduce. My file has carriage returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue was solved using .rtf extension

```
dlmwrite('C:\Users\amar-admin\Desktop\abc.rtf', m)
```

But, I still wonder if same is possible to .txt file

Answer (score 2):

You may want to set the [`'newline'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html#input_argument_d0e227543) option to `'pc'`:

```
dlmwrite('C:\Users\amar-admin\Desktop\abc.txt', m, 'newline', 'pc');
```

This will ensure that the file is created with a carriage return (`\r`) *and* a line feed (`\n`) at the end of each line, instead of potentially just a line feed, which could affect how it is displayed in certain text viewers. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1761051/52738) for more information about the differences between `\n` and `\r`.