# How to find occurrences of a substring="\\r" in a string="This is a \\\\\rtest \\n\\r string" in java using Pattern and matchers

Tags: javascript, java, spring, string, sorting

How to find occurrences of a substring="\r" in a string="This is a \\rtest \n\r string" in java using Pattern and matchers.

When I use

```
Pattern p4=Pattern.compile("\\r",Pattern.LITERAL);
```

Even then this is not working

It worked well when I have string="This is a \\rtest \\n\\r string".It have me correct count i.e..2

But for `string="This is a \\\\\rtest \\\n\\\r string"`.
It gave me incorrect count =1;

function to be called:

```
static int countMatches(Pattern pattern, String string)
{

    Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(string);
    int count=0;
    int pos=0;
    while(matcher.find(pos))

    {
        count++;
        pos=matcher.start()+1;

    }

    return count;

}
```

Comment: you need to escape the backspace by duplicating it

Comment: Use [edit] option and post your string using code formatting (`{}` icon on editors options). Otherwise we wouldn't know how many ``\`` you really have in your string and what exactly you want to find.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the String `"This is a \\\rtest \\n\\r string"` really does not contain two occurences of `'\\r'`. the first occurence is interprated by the compiler as the two characters `'\\'` (which is a single backsapce `'\'`) and `'\r'` (which is something unprintable)

This is also true for `"This is a \\\\\rtest \\n\\r string"` or any other not-even number of backslashes

Answer (score 0):

In string you can use `\\` if u want to escape character. So in your string

```
String string="This is a \\\rtest \\n\\r string";
```

In this string `\\\rtest` part is escaping the `\r` part with double backslash `\\`.

This `\r` has meaning in string library. 
You can read this question : [\r diff \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r)

So in your example \r could not see in your variable string. If you change the string with this you can get result as **2** ;

```
String string="This is a \\\rtest \\n\\r string";
```

in your string second part as `\\n\\r` there is saving the `\n` with `\` and `\r` with `\`.

In shortly , change the string to get result correctly. if you write double backspace before the anything , you will escape after char.