# Why does this regex work everywhere except a node program?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm not even looking for a solution at this point, just curious why my regular expression works in Firefox, Chrome and regex testers but not in Node 8.12, 10.11 and 10.12.

Here it is:

```js
var str = `import {User} from '..';
import {UserRole} from '..';

export class ServerUser {
  _id?: string;
  id?: string;
  userRole?: string;
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  description?: string;
  email?: string;
  telephone?: string;
  profileImg?: string;
  dateOfBirth?: number;
  registeredAt?: number;
  isMale?: boolean;
  password?: string;
  username?: string;
  media?: any[];

  /**
   * call this method to map the User to ServerUser
   *
   * @param {} user
   * @returns {ServerUser}
   */
  static map(user: User): ServerUser {
    const u = {} as ServerUser;
    [...etc.]
`;

var resultArray = str.match(/\s*[_u]id\?\:\sstring\;\s+([.\w\?\:\,\;\[\]\{\}\s]*)\;\n/m);

console.log(resultArray);
document.write(JSON.stringify(resultArray, null, 4));
```

In node the same regex used like this:

```
fs.readFile(serverPath, 'utf8', (err1, serverContent) => {
                    if (err1) return resolve(false);
                    const serverPropArray = serverContent.match(/\s*[_u]id\?\:\sstring\;\s+([.\w\?\:\,\;\[\]\{\}\s]*)\;\n/m)[1].split(';').map( el => el.trim() );
```

Throws an error:

```
...\gulpfile.js:383
                        const serverPropArray = serverContent.match(/\s*[_u]id\?\:\sstring\;\s+[.\w\?\:\,\;\[\]\{\}\s]*\;\n/m)[1].split(';').map( el => el.trim() );
                                                                                                                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at fs.readFile (C:\wink\winkular-cli\gulpfile.js:383:127)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)
```

Anyone?

Comment: @Pawel - What do you mean by it not working? Certainly it seems to work other than, of course, that `document.write` isn't supported in Node.js. What specifically isn't working? What result are you expecting, and what are you getting instead?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Upon re-reading the question I realise `str` is not just the first line. my fault.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hi! It works in browsers but not in Node.js. Sorry about the lack of info about how I'm using the regex in node - just added it at the end of the post.

In node I'm expecting it to return an array containing 2 strings, like it does in browsers. Instead it throws an error as if the regex didn't find any matches.

ps. I have confirmed that serverContent !== undefined when running the match on it.

Comment: So, what's the value of `serverContent`? It's hard to say why your regex doesn't match some unknown string.

Comment: Post code, markup, errors, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: @T.J.Crowder fixed (sorry about that - first time posting).

Comment: @vlaz the value of serverContent is the content of a .ts file (angular) i copied its beginning into the snippet at the top of my post and assigned it to the str variable

Comment: @PawełKrzemiński - The JavaScript engine in Node.js and Chrome is the same, so if you're getting different results, the reason is that the strings are different. You'll want to [debug the problem](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) to find out why.

Comment: @PawełKrzemiński are you sure that's the content? Because I'm not. The fact that you get an error indicates it. I've also tried your first snippet in a Node REPL and I am getting the match. So I'd suggest you log the content or debug and make sure `serverContent` really is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Thank you all! The solution provided by @barbsan worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is newline character in your regex: `\n`. 
Apparently you don't run node on Unix system, so you can:

- use [proper combination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1761064/7404943)

or:

- get rid of it

or (better):

- satisfy all of them, using `(\r|\n|\r\n)`

Comment: Using (\r|\n|\r\n) instead of the single \n fixed the problem. Thank you! (can't upvote yet unfortunately)