# Regexp for 2 new lines not match

Tags: java, regex, wiremock

In my Java project I need to match the next text.
I use **WireMock** to stub request. So I need to write regex to find desire requests and return stub response.
In WireMock I need to write regex to intercept http requests.

Suppose I has 2 jsons:

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    "action": "Handler:GET_DICTIONARY",
    "locale": "en",
    "data": {"dictionary_type":"EXCHANGE_RATES_AS_DICTIONARY"}
}
```

and

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    "action": "Handler:GET_DICTIONARY",
    "locale": "en",
    "data": {"dictionary_type":"MTS"}
}
```

I need to select only second json by regexp. The unique text to identify second json are:

on first line: `GET_DICTIONARY`

AND

on third line: `MTS`

What is a correct regexp for this?

I try this regexp but it not help:

```
GET_DICTIONARY\(.*\r\n\)\{2\}.*MTS
```

Comment: Why use a regex? Parse the JSON instead

Comment: I use WireMock to stub request. So I need to write regex to find desire requests.

Comment: Still, use json parser

Comment: @mvp In WireMock I need to write regex to intercept http requests.

Comment: Intercept http request and use json parser. If it doesn't parse, fail your test.

Answer (score -2):

here [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ecpo5R/6)

try this

```
GET_DICTIONARY(.*\n){2}(.*MTS.*)
```

Comment: Here correct regexp:   GET_DICTIONARY(.*\r?\n){2}(.*MTS.*)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r see a difference. I think there is no need to use \r?.