# RegEx Not Matching Carriage Return without Linefeed

Tags: python, regex

Why is [this](https://regex101.com/r/JfRvVE/5/) simple regex not matching a carriage return? For reference, my data is the result of a SQL query and I have replaced linefeed \n with a single space.

```
\r

SRUS55 KSLC 082010\r\r HMTSLC\r\r
```

Comment: `\\r` will do that. But there is no CR, there is a combination of ``\`` and `r` chars in your example. BTW, you cannot input a CR in regex101.com, it only supports LF line endings. I suggest providing an example in Python. Please share an exact snippet to test your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `\r` in your demo.

This is a newline character, either you were looking for `\\r` or `[\n\r]+` if your string happens to include newlines.

For a more in-depth answer, [see this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r).