# Environment variable has \r added

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ubuntu-18.04, dotenv

Environment variables were not working. Printed into bash the process.env and some variables have this \r at the end.

```
MAIN_DB_ADAPTER: 'sails-mongo\r',
REDIS_PORT: '6379\r',
```

Do you have any idea what's going on?
.env.local file looks like

```
export MAIN_DB_ADAPTER= 'sails-mongo'
export REDIS_PORT: 6379
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the `.env.local` file was written in with `\r\n` line terminations, but dotenv wants `\n` line terminations (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1761086/6759322)), and it's using `\n` to split the environment variables. You should be able to use the answers from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/138472/253519) post to convert between the two (TLDR: `sed 's/\r$//'`) or use an editor that supports switching between the two (like [Atom](https://atom.io), for example).