# InStr (VBA function) can't find vbCrLf

Tags: vba, find, instr

I would like to get a string up to the newline. For this I am trying to use InStr(text, vbCrLf), but the function returns 0. MsgBox displays the text considering the line jump. Why it returns 0?

' VBA

```
InStr(text, "/r") ' returns 0
InStr(text, "/n") ' returns 0
InStr(text, vbCrLf) ' returns 0
```

Comment: Have you tried vbLf ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Mathieu Guindon for noticing OP was looking for wrong character.

I was looking at your '\n' and jumped to an alternative I like to use which is the Chr code

```
InStr(text, chr$(10))
```

[Quote:](https://www.petefreitag.com/item/863.cfm)

> The ASCII character code 10 is sometimes written as \n and it is
>   sometimes called a New Line or NL. ASCII character 10 is also called a
>   Line Feed or LF

Comment: `vbCrLf` is `Chr$(10)` & `Chr$(13)` though. OP was just not looking for the right thing

Comment: @MathieuGuindon oooh while your here.... isn't Chr$(10) newline? So are you saying Chr$(10) & Chr$(13) is equivalent to \n ?

Comment: `vbNewLine` is `vbCrLf` (on Windows); `Chr(10)` is `vbLf`, and `Chr(13)` is `vbCr` ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon so \n is chr$(10) ? - that was what I was focusing on. I completely missed the other part. :-(

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1761086/1188513) explains it better than I could in a comment - `\r` would be the "carriage return", i.e. `vbCr` so `Chr(13)`

Comment: for future ref you can check an [ascii table](https://www.asciitable.xyz/images/ascii-table.png) to see what each `Chr(dec)` represents