# Junit test for println

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to write junit tests for System.out, especially system.out.println, but even after reading through related posts, i couldn't get to the solutions.

```
public static void hello(){
    System.out.println("Hello");
}


@Test void Test(){
  System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
  System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent));

  hello();

  assertEquals("Hello\n" , outContent.toString());

  System.setIn(System.in);
  System.setOut(originalOut);
  System.setErr(originalErr);
}
```

It works perfectly fine when i use print instead of println and remove \n from assertEquals, but whenever i try println with \n, the test fails with

```
 expected: <Hello
> but was: <Hello
>
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <Hello
> but was: <Hello
>
```

which even the error message looks the same. Is there any way i can use println and pass the test? Thank you

Comment: On which OS do you run this test? New lines differ per OS. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1761086/2003874

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is indeed the different line separators for Windows, I updated your fragment, I replaced `\n` with `+ System.lineSeparator()`

Locally on my Mac it works I expect it to be fine on Windows too with this change.

```
public static void hello(){
    System.out.println("Hello");
}


@Test void Test(){
  System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
  System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent));

  hello();

  // Changed the line below  
  assertEquals("Hello" + System.lineSeparator(), outContent.toString());

  System.setIn(System.in);
  System.setOut(originalOut);
  System.setErr(originalErr);
}
```