# I have a problem with scanf and giving input a char array with a for loop?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, char, scanf

When I run that, after the first iteration everthings looks ok, the for loop print "write char" twice and after wait for the input. From what I understand the values are not really assigned(not even in the first iteration). Some help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i;
    char a[100];
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++){
        printf("print char\n");
        scanf("%c",&a[i]);
    } 
} //this is my code
```

Comment: With what exactly do you need help with? `print "write char" twice`  vs `printf("print char\n");` - your code prints "print char" not "write char". Assuming `scanf` calls succeeded, the second element of `a` array `a[1]` is assigned to.

Comment: If you type `a` and return, you've entered two characters, so `scanf()` can read two characters in two iterations.  You've not printed any of the data; you've no idea whether it worked, but it probably did.  You might be better off using `" %c"` in the format string; the leading blank skips white space.  You should check that `scanf()` returns `1` each time (exiting the loop if it doesn't).

Answer (score 2):

Your `scanf` function is catching a carriage return (see Jonathan Leffler comment), using `getchar()` can solve this, like so:

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main(){ 
    int i; char a[100]; 
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){    
        printf("print char\n");  
        scanf("%c",&a[i]);   
        getchar(); 
    } 
    a[i] = '\0';
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%c", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Also the loop `for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++)` doesn't make much sense since you will leave the first `char` in your array empty, if you need to get 5 characters you should use `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`, and for good measure, terminate it with `'\0'`.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this: [Using fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209/10871073) - possible (probable?) undefined behaviour.

Comment: Waddya mean about "from the `printf` string before"?  The standard input and standard output are normally wholly unrelated.

Comment: It catches the newline (carriage return) from typing `a` (for example) and return — two key strokes, two characters in the input buffer.  Please remove the `printf` bit, at minimum.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler A Carriage return is something different than a newline. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica — yeah — the terminal probably mapped the carriage return that was typed into a newline, but I didn't want to get into the inner details of `stty icrnl` and `struct terminfo` in a 600-character comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char a[5];
    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
        printf("\nPlease input one character for the %d.Element: ",i+1);
        scanf("%c %*c",&a[i]);
    } 
}
```

where `%*c` discards the newline character `\n` which is left in `stdin` after the first character consumption.