# New line escape sequence going back to beginning of a line

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namepsace std;

int main() {
   cout << "Hello\nworld!" << endl;
}
```

On console it prints:

> Hello
>
> world!

But why *world!* starts from the beginning of a line wihout '\r' character?

Comment: ASCII-1968 (USAS X3.4-1968) allowed LF alone to be used as a newline, by allowing for an “optional implicit CR”. (Apple didn't get the memo until OS X.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While strictly speaking `\n` is newline and `\r` is carriage return, it's up to the particular console how these are interpreted. It seems your console (like most) does a carriage return on a newline.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays `\n` usually starts at the beginning of a new line.
Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r)