# .net core string operator does not execute with the excepted result

Tags: linux, .net-core

SDK: .net core 3.1
Environment: ubuntu 18/04

code:

```
Console.WriteLine("abc\n".IndexOf("\n"));
Console.WriteLine("abc\r\n".IndexOf("\n"));
Console.WriteLine("abc\r\n".Contains("\n"));
Console.WriteLine("abc\r\n".Split('\n').Length);
Console.WriteLine("abc\n".EndsWith("\n"));
Console.WriteLine("abc\r\n".EndsWith("\n"));
```

result:

```
3
-1   -> not as expected
True
2
True
False   -> not as expected
```

Comment: This behavior can be related to different handling of EOL symbols, have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase?view=netcore-3.1). Read this and you will understand what is happening.

```
Console.WriteLine("abc\n".IndexOf("\n", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
Console.WriteLine("abc\r\n".IndexOf("\n", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
Console.WriteLine("abc\r\n".Contains("\n", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
Console.WriteLine("abc\r\n".Split('\n').Length);
Console.WriteLine("abc\n".EndsWith("\n", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
Console.WriteLine("abc\r\n".EndsWith("\n", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings