# Syntax var names = string.split("\n"), make \r behind element of string field

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot in js, that will write to the minecraft white-list. When I read whitelist.txt and use `string.split ("\n")`, for example, a name is created in the field: Name\r. But I don't want this there, did I forget something? Thank you

```
const names = fs.readFileSync("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\pack\\whitelist.txt", {
  encoding: 'utf8'
});

var jmena = names.replace('\r', "").split("\n");

console.log(jmena);
```

Comment: i'd just want to say that you might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\r` is a carriage return character, and the backslash `\` escapes whatever character is after it. So the `replace` function is looking for a carriage return, but the string would be `\\r`.

So for you to escape the backslash `\` with another backslash.

```
var jmena = names.replace('\\r', "").split("\n");
```